# Proper Way of Watching Styles in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to resize images to match the `line-height` of the images container. I've set up ng-style appropriately:

```
<p class="text" ng-style="{'line-height': textHeight}">
       Press "<img class="mini up" 
                src="img/select-arrow.png" 
                 src="Up" ng-style="{'height': textHeight}">" 
           or "<img class="mini down" 
                  src="img/select-arrow.png"
                    src="Down" ng-style="{'height': textHeight}">" 
              on your remote control to select</p>
```

I want `textHeight` to update on load and then on resize events. What is the preferred method of doing this? Should I do it on init?

Can anyone provide me an example?

Comment: I don't get it. Where does the value of `textHeight` come from and what pattern should it follow?

Comment: I'm trying to set textHeight to the value of the line-height of the p.text and apply that textHeight value as the height of the images